# How to extract body in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

When I receive an object through POST, req.body looks like:

```
{ '{\n  "attrs" : {\n    "name" : "myName",\n    "books" : ': { '\n      {\n        "attrs" : {\n ...
```

How can I get the request to turn it into JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need to set the `Content-Type` of your request as `application/json`. For example, if you're using cURL, this means setting `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`.